# Upgrading python on Windows 10’s Bash Shell

Tags: python, linux, bash, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I was trying to update `python3` in the Linux Bash Shell for Windows 10.

Here is what I tried:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/python-3.6
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3.6
```

But I got the following error:

```
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.9) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 ghc
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I also tried searching if it will override my python 3.4 and make it inaccessible as in delete it and install 3.6, but found no results.

Is there a safe way to upgrade `python3` here

[EDIT]

After upgrading the shell to *16.04* using `do-release-upgrade`, the error goes away. Update can be done following this [link](https://www.howtogeek.com/278152/how-to-update-the-windows-bash-shell/).

Comment: This seems to be related to WSL, not [win-bash](http://win-bash.sourceforge.net)?

Comment: You are right about win-bash, I shall edit my question.

Answer (score 1):

First, I'd strongly encourage you to make sure you're running Windows 10 Fall Creators Update (or later).

Secondly, I'd recommend adding the `apt upgrade` step below:

```sh
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/python-3.6
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install python3.6
```

The upgrade step ensures that all your installed packages are upgraded to their latest version, and can often fix "errors while processing" other packages' installation.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. But the error is no longer reproducible after running `do-release-upgrade` to 16.04. Although for more info to work on, the `ghc` error not only comes here but quite a few other places where this dependency is there.

Comment: If the error is no longer reproducible, please update your OP stating so.

Answer (score 0):

That's a weird error, there might be something wrong with your dpkg. You can always try building python from source. This works in regular out-of-the-box Ubuntu, so it should run on Windows too.

```
sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev
wget www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.0/Python-3.6.0.tgz
tar -xf Python-3.6.0
cd Python-3.6.0
./configure --enable-optimizations
make
sudo make install
```

Save those commands to a file called python.sh, then run

```
chmod 755 python.sh
./python.sh
```

It can take a while, though, so be patient